# JPA 2.0 - embedded Id, manytoone not persisted

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have 2 entities (simplified version below):

```
@Entity
Client
@Id protected String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
protected List<Message> sentMessages = new ArrayList<>();

@Embeddable
MessagePK
@ManyToOne(/*cascade = CascadeType.ALL*/)
protected Client sender;
protected LocalDate dateTime;

@Entity
Message
@EmbeddedId protected MessagePK id;
@Column protected String message;
```

When I attempt to persist Message, it complains that client is a transient instance.

So, I tried putting a cascade operation there, but that also didn't work (it is commented out now).

I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't have a relationship (like @ManyToOne) in an @Embeddable.
Because an embeddable object has no identity of its own (lack of primary key) it needs to be treated only as a part of the entity that encapsulates it. From a database point of view, an embedded object is stored with the rest of the entity attributes in a single row.

You could use @IdClass annotation to create your composite key sender/datetime
see : https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/DerivedIdentifiers

Comment: But, isn't it the identify in this case since I'm using @EmbeddedId?  If not, what's the point of EmbeddedId

Comment: @EmbeddedId Is applied to a persistent field or property of an entity class or mapped superclass to denote a composite primary key that is an embeddable class. The embeddable class must be annotated as Embeddable.

Comment: Thanks - I started looking at @IdClass and think that is probably the direction to go.